# Relations between statements involving universal quantifier, conditional and biconditional

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

If we consider two predicates:

$b(x)$: x is a boy

$c(x)$: x is clever

Then, there are four statements involving $∀, b(x), c(x), →$ and  $↔$ . These are below along with my interpretation of their meaning. Correct me if I am wrong in any of these interpretations.

**(a)** $∀x(b(x)→c(x))$ - All boys are clever

**(b)** $∀x(b(x))→∀x(c(x))$ - If all are boys, then all are clever

**(c)** $∀x(b(x)↔c(x))$ - All boys are clever & all those who are clever are boys

**(d)** $∀x(b(x))↔∀x(c(x))$ - If all are boys, then all are clever & if all are clever then all are boys

I am trying to determine all conditional $(→,↛)$ / bi-conditional $(↔)$ relations between each two of above four. Between any two of these, if there is $↔$, then there is only one relation. However, if there is conditional relation in one direction, then conditional relation in other direction will be invalid. That is there can be $(→,↛)$. So at max there will be $4C_2\times 2=12$ such relations.

Now to understand these relations, I prepared below table. I considered that there are only two person in the universe $x_1,x_2$. $\{(b,c),(¬b,¬c)\}$ means $x_1$ is boy and is clever and $x_2$ is not a boy and is not clever. 
The truth values (in table) in boldface (all other than vi, viii and xiv) are one which I feel are correct, though I am not sure. The non bold-faced truth values (vi, viii and xiv) are ones which I am unsure. So, I am more likely make mistake with them.

[image]

Based on the truth values in above table, I prepared following relations:

[image]

**Q.** Are relations 1 to 12 correct?

**Q.** Also is there some fault in the example predicates $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ themselves?

Actually, I must doing similar for existential quantifier. But afterwards. But am I correct with all this thinking or am just over thinking? Or am severly screwed with my logics?

Comment: Not every statement in logic is necessarily true or false.  For some statements, there simply isn't enough information to tell.  So even if you can't conclude $w \implies z$ doesn't mean that you can conclude $w \not \implies z$.

Comment: Do you mean to say depends on the meaning of $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ and say it is not always the case that $(a)\to (b)$ (and other relations also). Can you give an example for which $(a)\to (b)$ does not hold?

Comment: $(a) \implies (b)$, $(c) \implies (a)$, $(d) \implies (b)$ are all provably true.  But $(b) \implies (a)$ is not a statement that can be proven true.  That  doesn't mean that $(b) \not \implies (a)$ is a statement which can be proven true.  $w \not \implies z$ means that $w$ is true and that $z$ is false.  You don't have enough information (axioms) to make that strong of a statement here.  So every case of $\not \implies$ isn't correct.

Comment: Thats nice point. I was thinking that $a→b$ holds if for all $a=true$, $b=true$ & if there is at least one case where $a=true,b=false$, then $a↛b$. That may not sound correct because books usually does not deal with $↛$. Also there is [wiki pagefor $→$](https://goo.gl/IaSME9) but I guess not for $↛$. However, at first glance it feels correct that if it does not satisfy the truth table of $a→b$, then it means $a↛b$. But I guess this definition of $a↛b$ is incorrect. It is $(a↛b)≡¬(a→b)≡a∧¬b$. Is this the reason? But then is there some operator saying "it is not the case that $a→b$"?....

Comment: [continued from earlier comment]....also does that means all non-implication relations (2,4,6,8,9,11) are incorrect, they are actually "it is not the case that $x→y$ holds"? Also are all implication rules (1,3,5,7,10,12) correct?

Comment: You can say that "B does not follow from A as $A \not \vdash B$", but that isn't a logical statement about truth tables, it is a procedural statement about expressions.  It is possible for $A \not \vdash B$ and $A \not \vdash \lnot B$.  You are correct that $(a \not \implies b)$ is the same as $\lnot (a \implies b)$ which is the same as $\lnot (\lnot a \lor b)$ which is the same as $a \land \lnot b$.